# How to call function of one controller from other controller in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call Listing function of testController from userController.
 I mark(//) the place from where i want to call function in following code. 
I am doing this in **angularjs**

```
function userController($scope, $http) {

                $scope.SignUp = function() {

                    $http.post('<?php echo site_url('angularjs/addToTable'); ?>', {'uname': $scope.username, 'pswd': $scope.userpassword, 'email': $scope.useremail}
                    ).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                        // Here i want to call Listing function of testController ...
                    });
                }
    }
    function testController($scope, $http) {
        $scope.Listing = function() {
                    $scope.users = [];
                    $http.get('<?php echo site_url('angularjs/get_list'); ?>').success(function($data) {

                        $scope.users = $data;
                    });
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you nest these two controllers in your markup, you can access the parent scope functions in the child controller. If not, this function might not belong into a controller, but a service, provider or factory.

```
<div ng-controller="testController">
  <div ng-controller="userController">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also define [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) that you can then provide to your controllers. Here you could define a service userManagement:

```
myModule.service('UserManagement', function() {
    this.list = function() {
        //..
    }

    this.signUp = function() {
        //..
    }
  });
```

This service will be accessible in your controller like this:

```
testController($scope, $http, UserManagement){
 // insert code here
}
```